Should I ask for physical recommendation letters now to avoid future issues with professors' availability?
I am planning to apply to universities abroad in the next two terms, but I haven't finalized which institutions I will be applying to yet. I understand that recommendation letters are a key part of the application process, and I have already approached a few professors about writing them for me.
One professor mentioned that, typically, students send them a link when the application is ready, and they fill out the recommendation online. My concern is that if I wait until I finalize my university choices, some professors might not be available to submit their letters due to scheduling conflicts or other reasons.
Given this, would it be advisable to ask my professors to write physical recommendation letters now, which I can later submit when the application process begins? Or should I wait and rely on the online submission system when the time comes? Also, are physical recommendation letters accepted by most universities, or is an online submission system required for all?

In what country are the universities where you would be applying?

There are many online systems that simply do not have the option to send physical recommendation letters, all of this has been digitalized.

I will be impossible for the professor to tailor each letter to the institution that will receive it if you do that; a disadvantage.
It is good to give the professor a heads up that you will be asking for about n letters coming up. This lets them think about what they will say and, if they like, write a draft that can be tailored.
And receiving institutions can be a bit tolerant about late arrivals of recommendations, realizing that professors are busy.
But if you really need such letters ahead of time, have the professor leave them with university/department staff so that they can be sent from your institution and not from you. This keeps the process clean.
And, some institutions might strongly prefer that an electronic version be sent directly to a system. But in some cases those can also be sent by university staff if they have been given instructions.
Having the professor pre-write them and give them to you for later transmission is likely the worst option. I'd recommend not suggesting that.

Yes, indeed. For several years now, with regard to all the (U.S. math) undergrads for whom I've written letters for (U.S. math) grad schools, the following happens: they complete their on-line application, listing me as "recommender", which triggers an email from that grad school, asking for my letter (and sometimes asking for a few other things). So I upload my letter that I've composed in advance, possibly tailored to the various programs (... the students having given me a list well in advance...)  No physical letters...

Check with the university's career center for letter of recommendation services. In the paper and typewriter days, it used to be very common that they'd hold letters and send them at the direction of the student; a few still do that or provide access to outsourced services.

Perhaps it is a security problem?
Some (small) number of applicants may attempt to provide fake recommendations.
If the recommendation comes from the professor's official university account, then the recipient can be reasonably sure that it really is from that professor.

If the prof. provides a student with the recommendation letters directly, then the student can choose whether they want to use them or not, and the prof. is not free to write a negative reference (if that is justified) as the student may simply open the letter and read it.
Generally only contact details are provided so that the institution can be confident that they are getting an appropriately candid reference that has not been seen by the candidate.  This probably explains the profs answer in the second paragraph.


I do not know where you plan to apply but almost all reputable schools will insist on getting a letter directly from a referee to preserve confidentiality and allow the referee all the candour they need.

Whereas you should preferably let people know well ahead of time where you plan to apply, writing the first letter of reference is long, and writing the 2nd takes a lot less time.  This is because the assessment and things to say about you are unlikely to change much or dramatically between the first and the second letter.

The deadline for students to submit applications is rarely the deadline for people to submit reference letters.

In some cases, the school will contact the referee directly once you have finished your application or after you have passed the first cut.  Schools know writing LoR can be a burden so in some case they only contact referee if they think the applicant have a chance.


